# DriveId can't be locally stored?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I get the following message when using the locally saved encoded to string and decoded back `DriveId` from the database.

`Attempt to compare invalid DriveId detected. Has local storage been cleared?`

Though it works okay for referencing the files.

Why do I save them is because when I initiate the upload by Google Play Services and the file is not uploaded yet, the `DriveId` has no resource id, so I store the DriveId with no ResourceId. Then when the file is uploaded, I replace the DriveId with the new one - with resource id.

The question is. Should I store only resource id whenever it's possible?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you are doing to save and restore the DriveId?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @SpiderMan, I moved to using Google Api Java Client for this project and use com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.getId(), so this particular problem in the question was not solved due to API change.

Comment: @DoctororDrive hahahaa. Happens

Answer (score 0):

`DriveId` will be provided when the commits has been made locally, you will get `DriveId` even in offline commit. But you can't get the `ResourseId` without committing the changes on the `Google Drive`. Once you receive the `ResourseId` after committing the changes, you can replace that with `DriveId`.

If you would like to get the `DriveId` from `ResourseId` then you can use the following code:-

```
String resourseId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" 

Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(mGoogleApiClient,resourseId).setResultCallback(idCallBack);

private ResultCallBack<DriveApi.DriveResult> idCallBack = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult driveIdResult) {
    msg.Log("onResult");

    DriveId id = driveIdResult.getDriveId(); //Here you go :)

  }
}
```

**NOTE :-**`ResourseId` is permanent and unique. `DriveId` is not unique to the file, it is different on each device.